# internet explorer 9 slow on some intranet websites

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

It seems we found some problems recently with some of our intranet websites.

When the page loads on one computer with IE9 the rendering is very slow (more than 2 minutes). If the page is loaded with firefox on the same machine, it renders almost instantly.

We tried on another computer with IE8 and Firefox 4 and IE10 beta the page loaded almost instantly also.

Another test we've done is to load a website on the internet with IE9, it loaded very quickly. It seems the problem comes with IE9 and Intranet (but not all of them).

What could be the reason behind that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem for me. I found out that IE9 somewhat was making wrong DNS queries (machines were in a windows domain, with PDC that was also the DNS, queries were no fully qualified)

In my case, there were just two local sites in the network, so I simply used a workaround and put them in the hosts file.

Comment: Interesting ... it seems for now it is only one computer and it access the website via IP. You think the dns problem "could" be extended to the IPs ?

Comment: I don't think so... In my case, the delay/slow load disappeared using IP to access local websites (and that's why my workaround worked)